# Is it possible to modify the style of the line between two points of a Line graph of an Active Reports Chart Control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, activereports

I would like to modify the segment line between two points of an
Active Reports NET7 version Line graph made with this object:

GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.ChartControl

I have been checking the properties of the chart control, and I was able to manipulate a single point of a serie as follows:

Me.ChartControl1.Series("MySerie1").Points.Item(1).IsEmpty = True

Setting IsEmpty to True makes the graph jump that x-axis value so it makes something like this (in the example it is jumping x=H24/9):

[image]

But I would like also to be able to modify the segment between the previous and next points to the one I made empty, making it a dash or a dot line like this:

[image]

I thought that something like the following code would do the trick:

Me.ChartControl1.Series("MySerie1").Points.Item(1).Line.Style=Chart.Graphics.LineStyle.Dash

But it does not work.

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Is it possible to modify a single segment?
> 2. Is there another way to do the same? (maybe two series instead of one, but I can not see right now an easy way to do that) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no, it is not possible to modify the single segment of series line.
2. yes, it can be done in 2 series, but you will need to choose LineXY series type instead of common Line type.
3. as workaround, i would recommend to add AnnotationLine to the chart.
   here is a sample of code(note: X = 0,5 for first point;X = 1,5 for the second point and so on):

Dim aline As New GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Chart.Annotations.AnnotationLine

aline.Line.Color = Color.White

aline.Line.Style = Chart.Graphics.LineStyle.Dash

aline.StartPoint.X = 0.5

aline.StartPoint.Y = Me.ChartControl1.Series(0).Points.Item(0).YValues(0)

aline.EndPoint.X = 2.5

aline.EndPoint.Y = Me.ChartControl1.Series(0).Points.Item(2).YValues(0)

Me.ChartControl1.Series(0).Annotations.Add(aline)

Comment: @GrapeCiteTeam thank you for the insights and the time you took for the answer, I am happy to see that there was not a very direct solution (I thought I was getting rusty!)

Comment: @GrapeCiteTeam just if you have time... may I ask you about another question regarding the Chart? Best Regards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753862/trying-to-show-a-label-instead-of-data-for-some-special-cases-in-active-reports